# How to set Session on LoginView in-built Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to set session in django after user logged in and destroy session on logout. i am using in-built Auth LoginView to Login

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='logout'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, django automatically destroys session in logout. basically it uses [flush](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush) at logout. Now, if you want to put some data during login, then you need to override `LoginView`. You can try like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login


class CustomLogin(auth_views.LoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
         login(self.request, form.get_user())
         self.request.session['some_data'] = "your data"
         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And use it in your url:

```
path('login/', CustomLogin.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
```

Answer (score 0):

In your auth_views add this

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
class LogoutView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
```

In urls

```
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```